# Google Motion Chart Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I took this code from their official site.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
        data.addRows([
          ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
          ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
        ]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i run the code, nothing shows up. What possibly can be the problem? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: It's working for me. Try previewing the page using MAMP or another local website manager.

Comment: not working :S that's so weird!!

Comment: Do you have anything in console?

Comment: what do you mean by console?sorry i'm quite new to this language/domain

Comment: I mean if you have any error reported in console. If you are using Chrome, you can open it with Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: If you are viewing the page from your local machine, and not through a webserver, the Flash security settings will prevent the chart from displaying.

Comment: This is written just above google motionchart examle: (Note that the following code will not work when loaded as a local file; it must be loaded from a web server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix this.

The problem was I had these lines in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',   'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
```

And then the java script executes google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});

It seems this "double load" is the problem

I removed the first line and it worked